# ReactJs route handle abc.com/:pageId

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am building an app to allow users having their own page on my app with url `myurl.com/:username` like `facebook.com/:username`. I dont want to include `#` in url. Below is my code:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
<Router>
 <Route path="/" component={HomeView}>
   <Route path="/:username" component={UserView}/>
 </Route>  
</Router>
```

Everytime I navigate to `myurl.com/mobject` it give me error `Cannot GET /mobject`
I am using `webpack-dev-server`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little mistake about the `<Route>`. From what I see (your import), I assume you're using RR v4. In v4, there aren't any nested `<Route>` anymore. That might be a problem. And for `#`, if you're using `BrowserRouter`, well you won't see that character when you're navigating using `<Link>`. `#` is from `HashRouter`.

An example of using it

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomeComponent} />
    <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
    <Route path="/about/team" component={TeamComponent}/>
    <Route path="/category/:id" render={ ({ match }) => <div>Category: { match.params.id }</div> }/>
    <Route path="/:slug" component={ ({ match }) => <h4>Slug: { match.params.slug }</h4> }/>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```